# Is there a way to get the length, last character, and last two characters of an input from Tkinter (Entry function)?

Tags: python, string, tkinter, string-length

I'm using the Tkinter Entry function, and need to know if there is a way to get the length, last character, and last two characters of the input.

Comment: Get the input back as a string, and extract what you need from the string itself. https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to get the value, and perform string operations on the value:

```
value = the_entry.get()
length = len(value)
last_char = value[-1]
last_two = value[-2:]
```

Comment: I tried that. The exact code I am using is ```from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
word = e.get()

length = len(word)
lastone = word[(length-1):length]
lasttwo = word[(length-2):length]


def callback():
        label = Label(master, text=e.get())
        label.pack()

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()

```

Comment: @AlexanderDua: I guarantee this will work, but you can’t call `get` until the user has had a chance to enter something.

Comment: You are correct, and I thank for your answer. What I found was that the `word = e.get()` has to be inside of `def callback():`. Everything is working great now, and, as I said, I thank you for your reply!